# Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in store.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-resource

I have an action in `store.js - vuex` called `signUserIn`. SignUserIn method is just a `http post` request. I have imported `Vue-Resource` in `store` file: `import VueResource from 'vue-resource'`, `Vue.use(VueResource)` and also in `main.js` - `store.js` has been imported. In my `SignIn.vue` component I dispatch `SignIn` action. I get back an error: `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`. What is wrong with my imports or code?

action:

```
signUserIn ({commit, getters}, payload) {
      let data = {
        _email: payload.email,
        _password: payload.password
      }
      let that = this
      that.$http.post(
        'url',
          data,
        { channel: 'default' },
        { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
      ).then(response => {
          const newUser = {
            email: payload.email,
            login: payload.login,
            cart: []
          }
          commit('setUser', newUser)
      }, error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
    }
```

Mutation:

```
setUser (state, payload) {
    state.user = payload;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` is property of Vue instance, in vuex store you should import Vue and use `Vue.http` to make requests.

```
Vue.http.post(
    'url',
      data,
    { channel: 'default' },
    { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
  )
...
```

Comment: @kabugh mark this answer as correct to close question :)